# ANTLR4 whitespace issue with separating digits from letters

Tags: antlr4, grammar

I have a grammar, which should differentiate between IDs, INTs, and IP addresses. My grammar has more patterns to recognize, but what I am struggling with is tokens like "123abc".

Typically a grammar would define WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip; which will ignore spaces, so in my grammar input like '123abc' will become '123' and 'abc'. This is the correct behavior of the lexer. However, I want the parsing to fail in this situation.

I've seen similar questions in SO and some other sites. I came up with a working solution (below) but it seems to me there should be a better way. I wonder if someone can suggest such a way.

Here is my (simplified) working grammar:

```
grammar Simple;

query: exp SP EOF;
exp: exp SP exp | term;
term: (name | sint) | name SP? '=' range_vals;
range_vals: SP? range_val SP? '..' SP? range_val;
sint: MINUS? INT;
range_val: (name | sint);
name: NAME;

MINUS: '-';
NAME: ALFA (ALFA_NUM)+;
fragment ALFA_NUM: ALFA | [0-9];
fragment ALFA: [a-z] | [A-Z];
INT: [0-9]+;

SP: ' '+;
WS: [\t\r\n]+ -> skip;
SL_COMMENT: '//' .*? '\n' -> skip;
```

Comment: What's the current behaviour? You want the parser to fail on the input `123abc`, so I assume it doesn't? Then what parse tree does it produce for that input?

Comment: Okay, I just tried it out and got "line 1:3 extraneous input 'abc' expecting SP". Isn't that what you want to happen?

Comment: @sepp2k. Yes, this is what I want. But my actual grammar contains much more stuff and I do not like it to have all these SP? spread all over it. I hoped there is another, more elegant solution (maybe lexer modes?).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question.

Answer (score 1):

If `123abc` produces an `INT` token and a `NAME` token, then there is no way to allow `123 abc`, but not `123abc` while also ignoring spaces. But what you can do is to make it produce a single token illegal token instead, like this (put this after the definitions of `NAME` and `INT`, so those will take precedence for valid names and numbers):

```
ILLEGAL_NAME: ALFA_NUM+;
```

Now `123 abc` will give you an `INT` and a `NAME` token, whereas `123abc` will give you an `ILLEGAL_NAME` token, which will cause an error in the parser because nothing matches it.